# React - How can I fire an Event listener just once?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say I have a button that only fires just once then the listener is removed.
I've done this with vanilla Javascript

```
const element = document.querySelector('#MyElement');
element.addEventListener('click', handleClick, {once: true});
```

I don't know how can I access this property with React synthetic events since this is putted directly in the component

```
<button id="MyElement" onClick={handleClick}>Click me!</button>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `useRef` to do the same. Demo [link is here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-na66eu)

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const ref = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current) {
      ref.current.addEventListener("click", () => console.log('Clicked only once'), { once: true });
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <button ref={ref}>Click on me (Once)</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const [avoidExtraCall, setAvoidExtraCall] = useState(false);

const handleClick = () => {
  if(!avoidExtraCall){
    //Do what you want here then
    setAvoidExtraCall(true);
    //This if statement will only be executed once
  }
}

return (
  <button id="MyElement" onClick={handleClick}>
    Click me!
  </button>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable in state, probably a boolean for this

```
function App {
  const [buttonClicked, setButtonClicked] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setButtonClicked(true);
    // continue with the function 
  }

  return <button onClick = {
    buttonClicked ? () => {} : handleClick
  } > Click < /button>

}
```

Or you could just return from the handleClick

```
function App {
  const [buttonClicked, setButtonClicked] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    if(buttonClicked){
      return; //simply return
    }
    setButtonClicked(true);
    // continue with the function 
  }

  return <button onClick={handleClick}> Click </button>

}
```

I would prefer the second option.

Answer (score 0):

Flip the state once the element has triggered its event :

```
handleClick() {
    this.setState({
        hasTriggered: true
    })
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {
                !this.state.hasTriggered ?
                <MyElement onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} /> : null
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```